# LaTeX Error only if certain citation is used

Tags: bibtex, errors, citing

I've got a strange problem, where texmaker throws an error only if I include the following citation:

```
however natural mood swings during weekdays might also have an
influence\footnote{see the appendix for "a case of the Mondays" at 
Google in Figure \ref{googmondays}}. As \citeA[p. 4]{yuliandresnerzhu} 
have pointed out especially Mondays can have a significant impact on employees mood.
```

If I remove `\citeA` it works ... Other `\citeA` citation work perfectly fine.

Here's the corresponding bibtex entry:

```
@INPROCEEDINGS{yuliandresnerzhu,
  author = {Yuliang Oliver Yao and Martin Dresner and Kevin Zhu},
 title = {Searching for the 'Monday Blues' in Order Fulfillment and its   Cure},
 year = {2010},
 owner = {johnny},
 timestamp = {2011.05.11},
url = {http://ssrn.com/abstract=1535117}
}
```

***EDIT:***

Here's the my custom build command:

```
  latex -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex|bibtex %.aux|latex -interaction=nonstopmode
      %.tex|bibtex %.aux|dvipdfm %.dvi|evince %.pdf
```

A working example should be:

```
 \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
 \usepackage{apacite} 
 \bibliographystyle{apacite} 
 \begin{document}

 \section{Design Decisions, why?}   

\subsection{Mood representation}
however natural mood swings during weekdays might also have an
influence\footnote{see the appendix for "a case of the Mondays" at Google in Figure}.
As  \citeA[p. 4]{yuliandresnerzhu} have pointed out especially Mondays can have a
significant impact on employees mood.



\bibliography{JF_MISNAAIFSMP_Biblio}             

  \end{document}
```

The are a lot of warnings thrown but strangely no error. What bugs me the most is that it actually stopped working after I inserted the citation, without changing anything else.

Comment: Can you please add a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/3240)?

Comment: It would be good if you would also tell us the error message.

Comment: Your bib record is missing an obligatory field for this reference type: you need a `booktitle` field. You also have no publisher or address fields, but these will just cause warnings, not errors.

Comment: thanks changing the reference type worked... At first I figured as well that this would only throw a warning, but still it somehow stopped latex.

Comment: I've added my comment as an answer.  It would be helpful if you could accept the answer (by clicking on the checkmark beside it) so that your question will be considered answered successfully.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your bib record is missing an obligatory field for this reference type: you need a `booktitle` field. Obligatory fields that are missing from a record will cause bibtex to throw an error; this will generally stop your build process.

You also have no publisher or address fields, but these will just cause warnings, not errors.